# Find missing branch names from lists

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find missing branch names from two different lists.

- List 1 (shown below as the "Branch List" tab), is the master list.
- The second list (shown below as the "P&L" tab(not to be mistaken with the "P&L List" tab)) will be fed by the master "Branch List".

As of right now, the "Branch List" list and "P&L" list both show the same branch names. However, if there are any more branch names added to "Branch List", I'll need to also add them to the "P&L" list.

To add more confusion, if there are any branch names taken out of the "Branch List", then I'll also need to take them away from the "P&L" list.

Lastly, the branch names in the "P&L" list are shown in a row. What I tried doing in the code below is first get the branch names from the "P&L" tab and show them in a single column within the "P&L List" tab. Then I've compared the two lists between "P&L List" and "Branch List" and shown any missing names within the "Compare" tab (column A showing branch names that are in the "P&L" tab, but not in the "Branch List" tab. Column B showing vice versa).

My problem is that I get an error when I run the code once, but when I run it twice, the code works. Any reason why this could happen?

```
Sub FindDifferences()

    Dim i As Long, ii As Long, sq1 As Variant, sq2 As Variant, m As Long


    sq1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Branch List").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    sq2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L List").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1)


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compare").Columns(1).ClearContents

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L").Activate
    Range("5:5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L List").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    For i = 1 To UBound(sq1)
        ii = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        ii = Application.Match(sq1(i, 1), sq2, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ii = 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Cells(m, 2).Value = sq1(i, 1)
        End If
    Next


    For i = 1 To UBound(sq2)
        ii = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        ii = Application.Match(sq2(i, 1), sq1, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ii = 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Cells(m, 1).Value = sq2(i, 1)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Sorry for the long read. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Use a dictionary for the branch names; if the item is not found when you loop through the rows, then it can be removed, when reconciling.  for adding new, you simply verify the branch name is appropriate against the dictionary.

Comment: The branch list gets updated within another system. So what I will basically do is export the list from this system and then dump it in this file I'm working on. Would using a dictionary be too redundant? Apologies for any confusion, but I'm relatively new to VBA

Comment: Oscar, the dictionary would be appropriate as it allows memory allocation via VBA and provide exact outputs.  You can loop through whatever size list to add items; see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why my above code doesn't work! Below is the same code but in the correct order:

```
Sub FindDifferences()

    Dim i As Long, ii As Long, sq1 As Variant, sq2 As Variant, m As Long


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compare").Columns(1).ClearContents

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L").Activate
    Range("5:5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L List").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    sq1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Branch List").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    sq2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("P&L List").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(sq1)
        ii = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        ii = Application.Match(sq1(i, 1), sq2, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ii = 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Cells(m, 2).Value = sq1(i, 1)
        End If
    Next


    For i = 1 To UBound(sq2)
        ii = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        ii = Application.Match(sq2(i, 1), sq1, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ii = 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Cells(m, 1).Value = sq2(i, 1)
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).